# How to get a random selection of items using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a way to get a random selection of items (no repeats) from a stream if you give it a random int stream?

As an example, I have a list of one thousand widgets and I want to randomly pick 25 widgets from that list.  Can I do this by generating a random int stream (with numbers from 0 to 999) and using this against the widget stream?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What items? from which stream? you give it means.. give to what? from where (what source) you want to get random selection?.. you're talking about shuffling numbers from the collection? please be more specific.

Comment: I suppose you mean `java.util.Random.ints()`, as opposed to non-existent (`java.util.`) `Random.IntStream()`.

Comment: I also think you mean the random selection is to be performed from the contents of a different stream.

Comment: What is less clear is (i) whether you are looking for a reordering of the objects  being selected, as opposed to simply accepting some and rejecting others; (ii) why it matters that you get pseudo-random numbers from a stream instead of directly from a `Random`.

Comment: I tried to give more details before but the question got closed because some guy thought that it was two different questions.

Comment: I'm sorry you had that experience, @GuyFawkes, but it appears that you have dialed it back too far.  What you're actually looking for is not clear from what you've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

- create an instance of Random
- generate a stream of values between 0 and widgetList.size()-1 inclusive.
- ensure they don't repeat (disinct)
- limit to 25
- grab the widget at that index
- store in a list.

```
List<Widget> widgetList;  // your populated Widget list
Random r = new Random();        
List<Widget> slice =     
    r.ints(0,1000).distinct().limit(25).mapToObj(widgetList::get).toList();
```

This should work. But if the upper bound of the list (1000 in this case) is less that the limit (25) it will never terminate.

You could also just shuffle the List and take the first 25.

```
Collections.shuffle(widgetList);
```